# How to display price as priceA + priceB in magento?

Tags: catalog, price, multistore

I have three different types of catalog.

> **1 - Price in terms of reward points required to buy the product.**

For example a mobile phone costs 30000 INR (this is how the price is given in the admin panel). The price is shown as **30,000 Points** in frontend.

[image: redemption points catalog]

> **2 - Price in terms of currency (INR).**

For example a mobile phone costs 30000 INR (this is how the price is given in the admin panel). The price is shown as **₹ 30,000** in frontend.

[image]

> **3 - Price in terms of both reward points and currency.**

For example a mobile phone costs 30000 INR, the price is given as 20000 in price attribute and 10000 in reward points attribute. The frontend should show the price as **₹ 20,000 + 10,000 Points**.

> note:
>       **These catalogs are placed in three different stores** (under a single website). So customer can only buy from a single type of catalog (no
>   mixup will occur).

As you can see I've done the first two parts with the help of [ET Currency Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html) extension.

But how can I do the third type?

I want it to be displayed like that (₹ 20,000 + 10,000 Points) everywhere (category page, product view page, cart page, checkout page, backend: sales/order page, invoices etc.).

> Payment gateway will consider only the currency i.e. value in Rupees.
>   The reward points need no validation, it'll be processed manually.

Can somebody show me the right direction?

Comment: Actually the price needs to be displayed all over the website, like cart page, checkout, backend pages, etc. Moreover the reward points aren't static, it varies according to the type of card selected by the customer.

Comment: Is there some other way than echo-ing the reward points all over the templates?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, please share the solution with us

Comment: No, it hasn't been solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

What about a new attribute for the products with the value of the Points in it and just change the `price.phtml` for the one store?

Should do it.

Comment: Actually that's my mistake only to show the catalog page in the screen shot, The fact is It needs to be displayed all over the website, like cart page, checkout, backend pages, etc. Moreover the reward points aren't static, it varies according to the type of card selected by the customer.

Comment: There are only two `price.phtml` to edit, so it should be easily achievable throughout the page. And then you need more attributes, or you put the information as JSON into the attribute.